# python: on-disk cache for functions receiving large inputs

Tags: python, dataframe, caching

I'm looking for on-disk cache of function results. (my) function arguments are typically data frames (up to several GBs).
I have searched for a few cache modules (mainly looked at joblib) and understood that they typically use crypto-like mechanisms to identify function input arguments uniqueness.

few (newbie) questions:

[1] could it be that these mechanisms will take substantial overhead for large inputs (for example more then few seconds to validate 1GB data frame input uniqueness)?

[2] is it possible that these mechanisms are likely not recognize slight differences in large data frames (for example a change in a single value for data frame with 1K columns and 1M rows)?

[3] is it possible (and recommended) to provide a unique key (e.g. file name from which the data frame was loaded, which I know for sure to be unique) for the input to save overhead time and avoid the possibility of uniqueness fail check?

[4] are there any recommendations for modules that would be effective for this type of caching?